# Impute missing data with mean by group

Tags: r, loops, missing-data, imputation

I have a categorical variable with three levels (`A`, `B`, and `C`).

I also have a continuous variable with some missing values on it.

I would like to replace the `NA` values with the mean of its group. This is, missing observations from group `A` has to be replaced with the mean of group `A`.

I know I can just calculate each group's mean and replace missing values, but I'm sure there's another way to do so more efficiently with loops.

```
A <- subset(data, group == "A")
mean(A$variable, rm.na = TRUE)
A$variable[which(is.na(A$variable))] <- mean(A$variable, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Now, I understand I could do the same for group `B` and `C`, but perhaps a `for` loop (with `if` and `else`) might do the trick?

Comment: Please create a minimal working example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
require(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(group) %>%
mutate(variable=ifelse(is.na(variable),mean(variable,na.rm=TRUE),variable))
```

For a faster, base-R version, you can use `ave`:

```
data$variable<-ave(data$variable,data$group,FUN=function(x) 
  ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x,na.rm=TRUE), x))
```

Comment: just for the fun of it, added a base-R solution above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `data.table` package to achieve this-

```
tomean <- c("var1", "var2")
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[, (tomean) := lapply(tomean, function(x) {
        x <- get(x)
        x[is.na(x)] <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
        x
    })]
```